# eigenvectors of linear map

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I'm stuck with this problem. For a map $L: X \rightarrow X$ with eigenpair $(\lambda,\varphi)$ prove $\varphi$ is also an eigenvector of $L^{-1}$,  $L^{k}$, and series expansion f $L$ and find their eigenvalues. 
My attempt: for $L^{-1}$, the eigenvalue is $\lambda^{-1}$, for $L^{k}$, the eigenvalue is $\lambda^{k}$ ? I appreciate your help.

Comment: For $L^k$, for a simple case, consider what happens when you compute $L^2(\phi)$.

Comment: @Sambo thanks for the hint. I think for $L^{k}$ the result would be $\lambda^{k}(\varphi)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint.* For $L^k$, use induction.

For $L^{-1}$, consider $\lambda L^{-1}\varphi=L^{-1}(\lambda\varphi)=\ldots$, though you need to assume that $L$ is invertible in order to achieve this.